# Need to translate line of code to fit into replaceWith() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, replacewith

so i am trying to replace a div when the window size is small with some new code inside of a div. i am trying to do this by using Jquery and replaceWith().

here's the code i need help translating with excape characters... is this impossible to do with php?

```
$('#container').replaceWith('<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?><img class=\"photo-img next\" src=\"images/<?php echo $image[\'name\']; ?>\"  data-cycle-hash=\"<?php echo $image[\'name\']; ?>\" data-cycle-desc=\"<?php echo $image[\'desc\']; ?>">
    <?php } ?>');
```

Comment: Javascript works client side, where PHP works server side. So if you really need server side data on a given viewport, you -for instance- need to do an Ajax request to get the data you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your requirements sounds like a responsive stuff. If i were you i would put the php code directly in html file like

```
<div id="yourInitialDiv">
  <!--Main content goes here-->
</div>

<div id="yourDivToReplace">
  <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
    <img class="photo-img next" src="images/<?php echo $image[\'name\']; ?>"  data-cycle-hash="<?php echo $image[\'name\']; ?>" data-cycle-desc="<?php echo $image[\'desc\']; ?>" >
  <?php } //end foreach ?>
</div>
```

The "yourInitialDiv" is the content you have, and "yourDivToReplace" is the content you have below a certain resolution. Next step is to modify them through css :

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) {
  #yourInitialDiv { display:none; }
  #yourDivToReplace { display:block; }
}
```

You just have to replace that `699px` with the resolution you want.

Comment: That is actually a much better idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side. Javascript is client side. If you try to insert a php code with javascript it will never work, because when javascript is called, php has finished his work there. You can use ajax instead, is a workaround to comunicate javascript with php.

Here you have a reference.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp

Comment: Anything but w3schools as a resource! Use [Mozilla's MDN AJAX Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).